# how should I send entities by socket on Java

Tags: java, json, sockets, entities

I'm into a web project which needs a bit of infrastrutcture, something in which I have not much idea really, so I'm here asking for your sage advice :).

The project is using spring for the MVC and have a connection with other project called tracker, made by sockets.

The point is that I need to create and entity object called task by web, and this entity should be send to the tracker, where will be processed, one first idea was sending the entity serialized, but doesn`t seem really good, because inside this entity are many others that aren't needed in the tracker. Also the tracker should send back some feedback about the task's realization.

I've read that making a JSON file with the data I need from the entity task and sending it to the tracker is usually a good idea, but I just wanted to be sure and know if there are other possibilities.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out [netty](http://netty.io/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of possibilities. I think JSON is a good option over XML.

For the JSON could you use Google Gson (https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) is a very useful and easy library convert JSON-JAVA and vice-versa.

The Java Objects serialization is another possibility. For send a java object over a socket could you do:

```
  URL urlServlet = new URL("http://...");
  URLConnection connection = urlServlet.openConnection();

  connection.setDoInput(true);
  connection.setDoOutput(true);
  connection.setUseCaches(false);

  connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", 
    "512");
  connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", 
    "application/x-java-serialized-object");

  ObjectOutputStream output = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
  output.writeObject(getOrdenesDTO());
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll give JSON a try, just because is a good option if someday I want to change the language of the project sending the data.

Comment: Sure, if you use JSON your project earns interoperability.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of possibilities: JSON and XML, for example, but serialization is the simplest one.  Instead of creating a JSON file or using an existing entity you can create a new, simple, Java bean containing only the information you really need and send it.

Of course here I'm assuming the the "traker" app will be developed accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion using JSON instead of serialization is easier to implement, however each field member has to be transformed into a string and back.

You can mark field you don't want to serialize with transient keyword.

Other option is of course the more difficult write-your-own socket protocol.